# How to use Filter functionality only

Tags: react-admin

I have a [react-admin](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/FilteringTutorial.html) application (v4.2.4) . I created a custom page where I need to have a filter toolbar on top. But it is not a resource list page, it's more like an analytics page. I handle on my own all data fetching (using react-query directly). So I would like to have all filtering functionality that react-admin has for List component (adding/removing filters, having it persist on store etc) but without any other functionality (resources, sorting etc) as they are not applicable in my case.

I upgraded (actually I am migrating) from react-admin v2.9. In that version, I had a `<Filter>` element inside of which I declared all my filter inputs. This element, if I am not mistaken, was using the redux store to store the filters selected by the user. So whenever and wherever in the component tree I needed access to the current filter of the page, I just connected my component to the redux store and had access to the filter. So my custom page had access to a filter functionality without the need of a List component. The filter was fed directly to a `react-query` `useQuery` hook and I had the data I needed.

In v4.x of `react-admin` I don't know how to exactly use a Filtering Context outside of a List Context.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the Filter outside of a ListContext in react-admin v4.

That being said, react-admin exposes low-level hooks for filtering, that you can include outside of a ListContext. This is not a documented feature, so you'll have to dig in the code to understand its usage.

https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/master/packages/ra-core/src/controller/list/useListParams.ts

The `<Filter>` component is still present in react-admin v4 (but not documented), for backwards compatibility.

Comment: In the end I actually used a ListBase component. I tweaked the data provider `getList` method to always return a result with two rows, each of which represented the analytics data I needed, based on the current filter. Then in the children of ListBase I used these data to render them exactly as I needed with my custom components. It looks like a totally custom page with the exception of the filtering toolbar which has all ra functionality baked in. Btw I love how much easier my life is with ra >= v4